# Increasing number of image per second with flash?

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cs4

I'm beginner in Flash CS4 and I'd like to know how to increase the number of image per second of my sequence because I want more smooth morphing. The time will not change.
Actually, I have 24 image per second and I'd like to put 48. Is there a way to make it automatically without changing all by hand.

for automatically : I mean, I just have to change my number of frame somewhere and flash will adjust my sequence and will use now 48 frame for 1s instead of 24 frame for 1s and regenerate morphing I use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean, 'automatically'?

There is a property in AS3 called `Stage.frameRate`, you may change this as desired in the code.

You can also change it under timeline of your app: [alt text http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/8052/fpsr.png](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/8052/fpsr.png)

It will, however, affect the length of your movie in seconds, so you'd rather count it by this formula:

```
MovieTime = NumberOfFrames / FPS
```

or:

```
NumberOfFrames = MovieTime * FPS
```

So you will have to change amount of frames by hand, if you wish to keep movie time consistent.

Comment: I don't know where to access AS3 Stage.framerate ?

Comment: Here are some links to get you started with AS3:
http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/683/1/Using-Document-Classes-in-Flash-CS3-Professional/Page1.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/?view=gettingstarted
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1):

Change the FPS in the properties. If you are doing any animations on the timeline this will result in a smoother appearance but also a faster animation. If you want the smoother appearance but same length of time of the animation then you will have to update your animation. Assuming you are tweening then you will have to drag the keyframes by hand. Painful yes.

One tip is that you can change the FPS playback via code as well, dynamically. This way if an animator has give you some animation at a certain FPS (say 24fps) but you want nice smooth animation for the rest then you can change the frame rate on the fly.